# How to implement utility type to merge interfaces into one with Object.assign logic?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I need a utility type that can merge two or more interfaces from a passed union into one, without resolving duplicated props to `never` but overwriting. It should work just like Object.assign but for types/interfaces.
Lets say we have three types:

```
    type A = {a: number};
    type B = {a: boolean, b: boolean};
    type C = {c: boolean};
```

I want to have some utility that can merge them into one:

```
type MergedType = MergeTypes<A|B|C>;
```

In the result i want to get the following interface:

```
type MergedType = {
  a: boolean, // overwriting, not `never` in case of using intersection (A & B & C)
  b: boolean,
  c: boolean
}
```

Is there any solution to reach this behavior?
I can only write a utility for two interfaces with separate generics arguments

```
  type MergeTypes<S, T> = Omit<S, keyof T> & T;

  type MergedType = MergeTypes<A, B>;
```

but I have no idea how to iterate over the union with reference to the previous argument to reach Array reduce logic.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: @wonderflame Yes, I saw it. However, it resolves duplicates as `never` and I don't see any way to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

```
type Pure<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] } & unknown
type Check<T, Eq extends ([T, V] extends [V, T] ? '=' : '!='), V> = T

type Assign<T, U> = Pure<Omit<T, keyof U> & U>
type AssignList<A extends any[]> =
  | A extends [infer F] ? F
  : A extends [...infer F, infer L] ? Assign<AssignList<F>, L>
  : never

type checkAssignList = {
  case1: Check<AssignList<[{ a: 1 }]>, '=', { a: 1 }>,
  // ^?
  case2: Check<AssignList<[{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }]>, '=', { a: 2 }>,
  // ^?
  case3: Check<AssignList<[{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }]>, '=', { a: 3 }>,
  // ^?
  case4: Check<AssignList<[{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { a: 3 }]>, '=', { a: 3, b: 2 }>,
  // ^?
}

const assign = Object.assign as <T extends {}, A extends readonly any[]>(target: T, ...sources: A) => AssignList<[T, ...A]>

const checkAssignList = {
  case1: assign({ a: 1 }),
  // ^?
  case2: assign({ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }),
  // ^?
  case3: assign({ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }),
  // ^?
  case4: assign({ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { a: 3 }),
  // ^?
}
console.log(checkAssignList)
```